# Microsoft Wireless Comfort Desktop 5000 Keyboard special keys

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I purchased a micrrosoft keyboard for its special keys such as XF86HomePage, while in my prvious model (the Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000) all the keys were configurable, at the new 5000 wireless model many keys don't key mapped to anything.
here's the relevant line in `lsusb`

```
045e:07b2 Microsoft Corp. 2.4GHz Transceiver v8.0 used by mouse Wireless Desktop 900
```

when in `xev` these keys show nothing. what's the lowest possible layer in which I can look for the keys been pressed?

Answer (score 1):

I think the kernel is the lowest rational layer.

The kernel will identify keys using *scan codes* which you can see in `sudo showkey -s` by pressing that key. The kernel also converts these keys to *key codes* which you can see in `sudo showkey -k`. If you want to remap some keys, you can alsodo it with the `setkeycodes` utility.

If you want to go even lower, `wireshark` can intercept USB traffic.

Comment: thanks for this answer.
unfortunately - `showkey` shows nothing for these keys.

didn't know wireshark can intercept usb traffic. will give it a try

Comment: If the kernel does not notice these keypresses - but only thee keys - I think you want to check that the keys are not dead physically

Comment: there's nothing physically wrong with these key. they work perfectly when I connect them to a windows system